# Why Standard C++ Defines Decl-Specifier-Seq Optional

Tags: c++, grammar

Why in the standard c++ grammar, the `decl-specifier-seq` under `simple-declaration` is optional?

```
simple-declaration:
 decl-specifier-seq(optional)  init-declarator-list(optional);
```

According to the spec, only the constructor, destructor and type conversion functions could have no `decl-specifier-seq` (section 9.2 or section 7 dcl.dcl). But all these 3 function declarations are members of a class, so they should be defined by another grammar rule separated from `simple-declaration`:

```
member-declaration:
 decl-specifier-seq(optional) member-declarator-list(optional);
 function-definition ;(optional)
 ::(optional) nested-name-specifier template(optional) unqualified-id ;
 using-declaration
 static_assert-declaration
 template-declaration
```

Here the `decl-specifier-seq` is optional as expected.  But why in a `simple-declaration`, it is optional, too?

Comment: The grammar is not optimized for compiler writers' convenience.

Comment: I think you could have skipped the last note. And a better formulated question IMO would be what are the technical reasons behind the current specification, and what would have been possible consequences of having it otherwise. Now it sounds like you are asking for an opinion, because you have a different one.

Comment: The c++ grammar isn't meant to include everything, but to always work for correct programs. There is an infinite number of "programs" that would fit the grammar, but are actually invalid C++ since C++ is by no means context free and has a lot of semantics in it.

Comment: Further note that even if you are writing just "a simple parser" then to parse all of C++ you need to have already almost a compiler since you need at least a memory model of your structs/classes to be able to properly parse C++.

Comment: Actually, we can build a fairly primitive but working parser by simply following the standard c++ grammar provided we limit the parsing to a very small subset of the language and that is all I want. e.g. a src file that is already known to be a valid cpp code (been compiled correctly by other full compilers) and the identifier names are known (obtained by using other compilation tools)

Comment: @JavaMan: Just hope it doesnt contain anything like `foo<sizeof(bar)>` or `foobar<decltype(blarg(blub))>` or similar nice t hings.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: it depends what you hope to get out of the parsing. If you only want an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), then the result of `sizeof` or `decltype` do not matter; only if you want an ABT (Abstract Bindings Tree) do you need all the semantic awareness. That said, C++ is messed up enough that a token of semantics slip into even obtaining an AST...